# MongoDb $filter condition to retrieve documents with redundant values in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDb collection as below :
Each document has a "bricks" array inside "currentVersion".
Now for few of Bricks array , there are some redundant brick ids.
I need to retrieve all the documents which are having redundant brick Ids.

```
{ 
    name: "page1", 
    "currentVersion" : {
        "bricks" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    name: "page2", 
    "currentVersion" : {
        "bricks" : [
            {
                "id" : 13.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 13.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    name: "page3", 
    "currentVersion" : {
        "bricks" : [
            {
                "id" : 20.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 30.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "name" : "page4", 
    "currentVersion" : { 
        "bricks" : [
            {
                "id" : 50.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 50.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 70.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My approach is below:

- I'm creating two arrays - 'origValuesSize'  and  'allValuesSize'
- If these two values are not equal , then that is the document with redundant values

Can you please suggest how I could filter the documents based on above condition.
Need help in the below piece of code

```
db.pages.find({},db.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: {
          origValuesSize: { $size: {$concatArrays : [ "$currentVersion.bricks.id" ]} },
          allValuesSize: {$size: {$setUnion : [ "$currentVersion.bricks.id" ]}},
          $filter: -->  Need Help Here to compare the above two sizes and filter accordingly                               
      }}
   ]
))
```

- Edit : 1

My Expected Result would be as below:
I need to display only those Documents which are having redundant brick Ids in "bricks" array .

```
{ 
    name: "page2", 
    "currentVersion" : {
        "bricks" : [
            {
                "id" : 13.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 13.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
{ 
    "name" : "page4", 
    "currentVersion" : { 
        "bricks" : [
            {
                "id" : 50.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 50.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 70.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you show your expected result? both the points are not clear can you please explain more.

Comment: I have added the expected result . Actually I'm trying one approach using Aggregation. `db.pages.find({},db.aggregate( .. ) `  , where I take two Arrays of the brick Ids  - One using $setUnion and other using  $concatArrays  ,  My logic is to compare the sizes of these two arrays . If these two Arrays are not equal length , then that document contains redundant Brick Ids , which I need to display

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression with aggregation operator in match stage,

- `$size` to get total elements in `currentVersion.bricks`
- `$setUnion` to get total uniue `id`s in `currentVersion.bricks.id`, and `$size` tot get total elements
- `$ne` to match both size should not same

```
db.pages.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          { $size: "$currentVersion.bricks" },
          { $size: { $setUnion: "$currentVersion.bricks.id" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bQYcANyOsZi)

---

MongoDB +3.2,

- `$project` to show required fields
- get size of both and match `$eq` conditions, it will return true when both same otherwise false
- `$match` isEqual is false

```
db.pages.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      currentVersion: 1,
      isEqual: {
        $eq: [
          { $size: "$currentVersion.bricks" },
          { $size: { $setUnion: "$currentVersion.bricks.id" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { isEqual: false } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_7YRSeste6T)

Comment: I tested this on my personal laptop . This is working . My Mongo version is 4.2.2.  But when I test this on my office laptop , I am getting an error  " Unknown top level operator  $expr "  . I am using Mongo version 3.2.2 in my work . Can you please suggest  alternative in 3.2.2  ?

Comment: check added option, I am not sure the new option should work.

Comment: I am getting an error  "The Argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO" . This could be because we have few documents which have the 'bricks' array Empty ( or does not exist) . Can we check before hand if the document contains the "bricks" array and then do the comparison ?  like using  $isExists  etc.  ?

Comment: what do you mean by "bricks"? its null or empty object {}, or empty array [], or field does not exists?